# Logback: how to change log directory from "tomcat/bin" to application related?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, slf4j, logback

I want to use **slf4j** with **logback** for logging.

You can see my logback.xml below:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILE-MODULE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>module.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>
                %date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="module" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-MODULE" />
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

The problem is: when I deploy my application to Tomcat, log file is stored in **tomcat/bin** folder, and I want to store it in myapp folder (**tomcat/webapp/myapp**).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I solved my problem but it is not very good solution (by my opinion).

First of all I put absolute path to log file in .property file. For example:

```
logback.log.location=d:\Tomcat\tomcat_8.0.0-RC5\webapps\module\logs
```

Then I use that property in my logback.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <property file="src\main\resources\system_config.properties" />
    <appender name="FILE-MODULE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${logback.log.location}\module.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>
                %date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="module" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-MODULE" />
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

More details you can see [here](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#variableSubstitution). This is an [example](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-examples/src/main/java/chapters/configuration/variableSubstitution3.xml), that I use.

But in solution above we have environment specific absolute path to the logs. This is ugly. Of course, we can use system variable **CATALINA_HOME** to avoid absolute path. But, as I know, CATALINA_HOME can be undefined. Or, we can use another instance of tomcat, that is not in CATALINA_HOME.

Maybe someone have more nice solution that will be environment independent?

---

**UPDATE**

Another solution:

Just use relative (to tomcat\bin) path instead absolute in logback.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILE-MODULE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>..\webapps\module\module.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>
                %date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="module" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-MODULE" />
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

It was the first idea, that I try to implement. I don't know, why it didn't work before. Maybe there were other problems. Moreover [this](http://java.dzone.com/tips/do-not-use-relative-path) and [this](http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2010/08/do-not-use-relative-path-with-logback.html) articles confused me.

But now this solution work fine. This is exactly that I am looking for =)

Answer (score 6):

If you do not want to save your logs in Tomcat's bin folder then use `${catalina.base}` as file path prefix in **logback.xml** file.

```
<file>${catalina.base}/logs/log.log</file>
```

Here log file will be saved in existing logs folder of Tomcat instead of bin.

Comment: Works nicely when running spring-boot from maven!